# Error when changing the height value of a constraint

Tags: swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

In my code I am changing the height constraint that was linked through a Ib Outlet "collectionViewHeightConstraint"

Whenever I run the app errors pop up stating that there's conflicting constraints. I tried to call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` but nothing really changes.

Ironically, the error is only called when the first three cells are initialized. However if I take out the `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()`, then the errors pop up whenever I scroll the tableview.

```
class MonthWeekTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var monthLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dayCollectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var monthYear: (String,String) = ("","") {
    didSet {

        monthLabel.text = self.monthYear.0

        guard let _maxDate = DateFormat.returnNumberOfDaysInMonth(month: self.monthYear.0, year: self.monthYear.1) else {fatalError("Tuple Error")}
        maxDate = _maxDate

        firstDay = DateFormat.getFirstOfMonth(year: self.monthYear.1, month: self.monthYear.0)

        let extra = maxDate - 36 + firstDay

        if extra > 0 {
            extraCalendarItem = extra
        } else if extra <= -7 {
            setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
            collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 270

        }
    }
}
var firstDay: Int = 0 {
    didSet {

        dayCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

var extraCalendarItem: Int = 0 {
    didSet {

        setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 270
    }
}

var dayNumber: Int = 1

var maxDate: Int = 30

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    dayCollectionView.delegate = self
    dayCollectionView.dataSource = self
    dayCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "DayCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DayCollectionViewCell")
    dayCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    if extraCalendarItem > 0 {
        return 6
    }

    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 5 {
        return extraCalendarItem
    }
    return 7
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let _cell = cell as! DayCollectionViewCell
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && firstDay > indexPath.row + 1) || dayNumber > maxDate{
        _cell.isHidden = true
    } else {
        _cell.dayLabel.text = String(dayNumber)
        dayNumber += 1
        _cell.isHidden = false
    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DayCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DayCollectionViewCell


    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width / 7, height: 45)
}

override func prepareForReuse() {

    dayNumber = 1
    extraCalendarItem = 0

    updateConstraints()
}

override func updateConstraints() {

    collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 225
    super .updateConstraints()
}

}
```

Comment: the error clearly mentioning you are violating constraints, check your xib file and try to change constraint height there you can get clear problem there.

Comment: I linked an Ib outlet  that holds the value of the height constraint and changed the constant of that Ib Outlet

Comment: My point is if you change this value inside storyboard or xib file, they should not give error there as well, if you face error there then you have to check your other constraint that makes an impact on it.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh sorry I missed read your first comment, when i changed the constraint's constant the same error showed (involving the original value for the constant). So, I have come to the conclusion that there's another contrainst. However, I can't find where I initialized it, or even if I did.

Comment: Yeah better to dig out more,